# Using Linq to EF to search using a array as search parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have already read and tried several links from here but none of them are quite a good fit.

I have a query that currently is searching using a number of or "||" clauses that I need to replace with a dynamicly assigned list.  It can be an array or a List<>

My current code:

```
    var mainPull = (from c in cDb.DistributionStopInformations
                    join rh in cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders on c.Route_Code equals rh.Route_Code
                    where c.Created_By == null && c.Company_No == 1 &&
                   (c.Customer_No == 228 || c.Customer_No == 227) &&
                   (c.Branch_Id == "MEM" || c.Branch_Id == "TXK" || c.Branch_Id == "TUP" || c.Branch_Id == "LIT")
                   &&
                    c.Shipment_Type == "D" &&
                   (c.Datetime_Created > dateToSearch || c.Datetime_Updated > dateToSearch) &&
                   rh.Company_No == 1 &&
                   rh.Route_Date >= routeDateToSearch
                    orderby c.Unique_Id_No descending
                    select new
                    {
                        c.Datetime_Updated,
                        c.Datetime_Created,
```

I need something like this (psedocode)

```
 string[] brancheSearchList = new string[] { "TUP", "LIT" };
            List<string> branchList = new List<string>();
            branchList.Add("TUP");
            branchList.Add("LIT")


            var mainPull = (from c in cDb.DistributionStopInformations
                            join rh in cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders on c.Route_Code equals rh.Route_Code
                            where c.Created_By == null && c.Company_No == 1 &&
                           (c.Customer_No == 228 || c.Customer_No == 227) &&
                           (c.Branch_Id IS IN branchesSearchList)
```

Comment: `list.Contains(c.Branch_Id)` should generate `WHERE column IN (...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.Contains` should generate `WHERE <column> IN (<comma separated values>)`

```
var branches = new[] { "TUP", "LIT" };
var result = 
    cDb.DistributionStopInformations
       .Join(cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders, info => info.Route_Code, h => h.Route_Code)
       .Where(info => info.Created_By == null)
       .Where(info => info.Shipment_Type == "D")
       .Where(info => branches.Contains(info.Branch_Id)) // WHERE Branch_Id IN (...)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you Fabio.
All it needed was your comment nudge in the right direction:
 brancheSearchList.Contains(c.Branch_Id) &&